# How should I define my polymorphic tables?

Tags: database, laravel

I have a post table that could be either video posts, text posts or picture posts, and a post belongs to a group. I think polymorphic relations are the right way to go, but my table looks kinda odd.

My post table:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| postable_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| postable_type | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| group_id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| upvotes       | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| downvotes     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| created_at    | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

text_posts table:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(130)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| body       | text             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

video_posts table:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| title      | varchar(130)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| path       | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| body       | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

picture_posts table:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| path        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| body        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| is_external | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| created_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

I looked at the example from laravel.com. It states that "Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model, on a single association. " But in the situation, my 'Post' should not belong to 'Video post' or 'Text post' etc. Instead 'Video post' or the like should belong to 'Post'. How can I improve my tables??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It looks like `Many To Many` Polymorphic Relations:

According to your tables in question your common table is `posts` and you want build relationship between other three different entities (tables), in other words all three tables (`texts`, `videos` and `pictures`) will share `posts` table, so for example, you have three tables like these (each one with `id` as `Primary Key`):

```
texts  table   |
videos table   |--- posts
pictures table |
```

Each table should be related with `posts` table so you need three separate tables and three models for each like;

```
Table                  | Other Personal Fields   |  Model
------------------------------------------------------------
texts (with id PK)     | title, body             |  Text
videos (with id PK)    | title, path, body       |  Video
pictures (with id PK)  | path, body, is_external |  Picture
```

The main/common table is `posts`, put all common fields in this table:

```
id (PK)       |
group_id      |
upvotes       |--- These are common/sharable fields by other three models
downvotes     |
created_at    |
updated_at    |
```

Fourth table `postables` for relationship between `POST` and all others (Text, Video and Picture):

```
post_id       | Always id of posts table
              | These two fields will build relation
postable_id   | id of texts or videos or pictures
postable_type | The model/type: Text/Video/Picture
```

Three models opposite to `Post`:

```
// Text: In the postables table postable_id
// will be texts_id and type will be Text for text_post
class Text extends Eloquent {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Post', 'postable');
    }
}

// Video: in the postables table postable_id will
// be videos_id and type will be Video for video_post
class Video extends Eloquent {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Post', 'postable');
    }
}

// Picture: in the postables table postable_id will
// be pictures_id and type will be Picture for picture_post
class Picture extends Eloquent {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('Post', 'postable');
    }
}
```

The `Post` model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function texts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Text', 'postable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Video', 'postable');
    }

    public function pictures()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Picture', 'postable');
    }
}
```

In `postables` table data could be like this:

```
post_id | postable_id  |  postable_type
---------------------------------------
   1    |      1       |      Text      // In postable_id 1 is id of texts table
   1    |      1       |      Video     // In postable_id 1 is id of videos table
   1    |      1       |      Picture   // In postable_id 1 is id of pictueres table
   2    |      3       |      Text      // In postable_id 3 is id of texts table
```

Usage:

```
$post = Post::find(1);
$postsHastTextPosts = $post->texts();
```

Reverse usage (`Text`):

```
$text = Text::find(1);
$text->posts()->first()->group_id;
$text->posts()->first()->upvotes;
```

Reverse usage (`Video`):

```
$vdo = Video::find(1);
$vdo->posts()->first()->group_id;
$vdo->posts()->first()->upvotes;
```

Reverse usage (`Picture`):

```
$picture = Picture::find(1);
$picture->posts()->first()->group_id;
$picture->posts()->first()->upvotes;
```

This could be done using `many to many` polymorphic relationship. All three models (`Text`, `Video` and `Picture`) can share same common `POST` properties, means in one group (group_id) all three types of models could belongs to.

In this `many-to-many polymorphic` relationship using one table (`postables`) three individual `pivot` tables (`post_text`, `post_picture` and `post_video`) has been excluded.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question though, what makes it Many to Many polymorphic instead of the traditional polymorphic relations??

Comment: Because you are sharing same thing with other models where it better suits `many-to-many` using reverse relation but it could be done in other ways as well, as normally `many-to-many` with `pivots`.

Comment: So in what situation the traditional polymorphic is suitable,is it when they dont share common table?

Comment: I rarely use it because it's possible to do similar thing using `one-to-many`, for example, `Photo` could belong to two different models and in this case `Laravel` gave an example of a `polymorphic` relationship but I can do same thing `using one-to-many`, you just try to do `polymorphic` relationship using `one-to many/non-poly` you can do it and you'll figure it out.